# Why we are allowed to create an object of a class inside the same class?

Tags: java

I am just trying to figure out why it is possible to do such thing but it is not possible in some other programming languages like C++. 
Here is an example of what I am asking:

```
public class A{
    private A objectOfTheSameClass;
    public A()
    {
       objectOfTheSameClass=new A();
    }
}
```

Comment: go and try, there'll you get trouble, since you'll create an infinite stack of A instances, and run out of resources.
In other instances, why shouldn't we able to do so?

Comment: i thought that object A will hold a reference to itself when instantiated. I developed my own LinkedList following a tutorial and it used the same technique. For example holding a reference of the next node inside the current node

Comment: Why shouldn't it be allowed? Ofc the above would cause trouble but a language can't shield a developer from every stupid thing they could do.

Comment: @johndoe: It *can* hold a reference to itself, though in your example you create a reference to a new instance.  But why shouldn't this be allowed?

Comment: *"...but it is not possible in some other programming languages like C++"* What makes you think you can't do the equivalent in C++?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just looked at a post made by someone on StackOverFlow and the answer was that you can get around that in C++.

Comment: @johndoe: There's no "getting around" it required. Your Java above, translated to the equivalent C++, compiles just fine. (And fails when run for the same reason.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Aha okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's not explicitly prohibited.

[JLS section 8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) that defines that body of a constructor does not mandate a compile-time error for such a case. The only case when a compile-time error should happen is when a constructor invokes itself with `this`:

> It is a compile-time error for a constructor to directly or indirectly invoke itself through a series of one or more explicit constructor invocations involving `this`.

More precisely:

> Except for the possibility of explicit constructor invocations, and the prohibition on explicitly returning a value (§14.17), the body of a constructor is like the body of a method (§8.4.7).

Since a method is allowed to invoke itself (recursion), a constructor is also allowed to do the same.

This will not compile because it calls `this`:

```
public class A{
    private A objectOfTheSameClass;
    public A() {
       objectOfTheSameClass= this();
    }
}
```

Your code, although it compiles, will throw a `StackOverflowError` because the constructor of `A` creates itself a new instance of `A`. The compiler can't detect every infinite loop in your code...

Comment: So it is possible if you have another constructor with Parameters and create an object of the same class using the default constructor or any other constructor?

Comment: @johndoe You can pretty much do what you want. The only thing is not to call the same constructor with `this`.

Comment: So basically creating the object of the same class inside that same class will equivalent to an object inside another object right?

Comment: @johndoe I'm not sure I understand. But what your code does is that to initialize an `A`, it tries to initialize another `A`. That cannot terminate, hence the infinite loop and the StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful sometimes, for example in the "singleton" pattern is used  to have exactly one instance of a class by creating an object of the same class as a class field, making it accessible via a public method and making the constructor private.

The instances are not created until the runtime, so the class is fully defined. It's up to you to use this in a proper way.